# Can the limit of a sequence be $+\infty$?

Tags: analysis

The proposition comes from the textbook of Tao Analysis:

> Proposition 6.4.12. Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^∞ $ be a sequence of real numbers, let $L^+$
> be the limit superior of this sequence, and let $L^-$ be the limit inferior of
> this sequence (thus both $L^+$ and  $L^-$ are extended real numbers).
> Let $c$ be a real number. If $(a_n)_{n=m}^∞ $  converges to $c$, then we must
> have $L^+$ = $L^-$ = $c$. Conversely, if $L^+$ = $L^-$ = $c$, then $(a_n)_{n=m}^∞ $
> converges to $c$.

My question is: Can we set c to be an extended real number? So if $L^+$ = $L^-$ = $c$=$+\infty$, then $(a_n)_{n=m}^∞ $
converges to $+\infty$. I'm just wondering if the limit of a sequence can be $+\infty$. If yes, then the sequence (1,2,3,$\dots$) has a limit of $+\infty$.

Comment: Are you essentially asking why Tao only considers real $c$ as opposed to extended real $c$?

Comment: You cannot take $c=+\infty$ since $c$ a point in $\mathbb{R}$ and not in $\Bbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}.$

Comment: yes, can we set c to an extended real number? so we have limit of sequence (1,2,3,...) be $+\infty$, like in the supremum of a set or sequence can be $+\infty$  @BrianMoehring

Comment: @AndrewLi, that proposition is correct even if $c=+\infty$ or $c=-\infty$ and in these cases we say that the sequence diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions in reverse order:

> I'm just wondering if the limit of a sequence can be $+\infty$. If yes, then the sequence $(1,2,3,\ldots)$ has a limit of $+\infty$.

This is perfectly fine.  It's a true statement that $(1,2,3,\ldots)$ has a limit of $+\infty$ in the extended real numbers.

> Can we set $c$ to be [any] extended real number? So if $L^+ = L^- = c=+\infty$, then $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $+\infty$.

This, however, is not okay.  By convention, if a sequence of real numbers *converges*, then its limit is a real number.  Therefore, the phrase "$(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $+\infty$" is either false or nonsense.  In the former case, your statement following "So" is false when $L^-=c=+\infty$, and in the latter case, it's not even a logical statement.

You may write the following analogous statement for the infinite extended real case:

> Let $c \in \{-\infty, +\infty\}$ be an extended real number. If $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ diverges to $c$, then we must
> have $L^+ = L^- = c$. Conversely, if $L^+ = L^- = c$, then $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ diverges to $c$.